# Using Execute Scalar Method to retrieve Foreign KEY ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I have two database tables, one is

```
ORDERS: OR_ID (PK), U_NAME, OR_TotalPrice, OR_STATUS, PROMO_ID
```

and the other,

```
Order Details: OR_ID(FK to ORDERS) Product_ID, OR_QTY, Product_TotalPrice
```

When I execute a scalar method to retrieve the OrderID from an Order, I cant seem to use that OrderId to populate my OrderDetails using that ID.

Here's my code;

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=ProjectDB; Integrated Security=SSPI");
        conn.Open();
        String addOrder = "INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES(@U_NAME,@OR_TOTALPRICE,@OR_STATUS,@PROMO_ID) SELECT CAST(scope_identity() as int)";
        String addDetails = "INSERT INTO Order_Details VALUES(@OR_ID,@PRODUCT_ID, @OR_DE_QTY, @OR_DE_TotalPrice)";

        SqlCommand cmdATO = new SqlCommand();
        using (conn)
        {
            cmdATO.CommandText = addOrder;
            cmdATO.Connection = conn;
            cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("@U_NAME", name);
            cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OR_TOTALPRICE", finalTotal);
            cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("OR_STATUS", false);
            cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("PROMO_ID", 0);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                orderID = (int)cmdATO.ExecuteScalar();  //Gets Order_ID
                lblError.Text = ""+orderID;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if (orderID != 0)
        {
            using(conn)
            {
                cmdATO.CommandText = addDetails;
                cmdATO.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {

                        cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OR_ID", orderID);
                        cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUCT_ID", dt.Rows[i]["product_ID"]);
                        cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OR_DE_TOTALPRICE", dt.Rows[i]["totalprice"]);
                        cmdATO.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OR_DE_QTY", dt.Rows[i]["quantity"]);

                        cmdATO.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ez)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ez.Message);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your connection was disposed by the first `using` you had it in.  I'd expect you'd get an error message about that when you try to use it again.  Either create two separate connections or there should only be one `using` statement for the entire method.

Comment: Also if you want to use your insert command with multiple values you need to create and execute it in the for loop.  And it's best to create a new command instead of reusing an old one.

Comment: What are you getting in your orderID variable? And what is there in your datatable?

Comment: @Atk Yes I've retrieved it from the Datatable but when using that, I cant seem to populate my Order_Details table

Comment: Provide a screenshot of what's there in each of your variable so that we can help you.